# How to return a promise after checking the result of one promise before calling another promise

Tags: javascript

I have two functions returning promises and I'm using them *independently* as:

```
getLocal().then(...)
```

and

```
getWeb().then(...)
```

However now I ran into a weird problem:
1) I need *a third* function that *returns a promise*
2) The function must first check if `getLocal()` has the data. If it has, then *return this promise*.
3) If  `getLocal()` doesn't have the data, then *return the promise* of `getWeb()`

Hope I'm clearer... any help?

Comment: How about using async await approach?

Answer (score 4):

```
async function f() {
  return await getLocal() || await getWeb();
}
```

Comment: Ahh you made it look so simpleXD Thank you so much:) `getLocal()` has to be called two times?

Comment: It depends what you want to return, the promise or the value resolved?

Comment: Originally, the caller expects the promise from `getWeb`. Now I'm caching data locally, so ideally I want this new third function to return promise only...

Comment: Edited according to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all([getLocal(), getWeb()]).then(([local, web]) => {
  return local|| web
});
```

Comment: I do not recommend this as it sounds like it is supposed to be a "fallback" where you go to the web if and only if the data is not available locally. This will always hit both sources and delay until they have both responded.

Comment: If I understand Promise.all runs both `getLocal` and `getWeb`. But I don't want to run `getWeb` if the data is available in `getLocal`.. Thank you:)

Comment: @Chase I agree with you but the OP has mentioned that they want to return the response of either of two with the condition, not they want to call the methods on the condition. also, comment `I'm using them independently ` is confusing if it's so they are not being called `independently`.

Comment: @AZ_ I see `independently` was a bit confusing.. I shouldn't have used that haha you're awesome:)

Comment: @beccaboo np, however, I don't suggest using `return await` as its redundant and an antipattern without a `try-catch` block, also using `||` operator will create a problem if  `getLocal` throws an error. one-liners are cool but not always good. better use `.then` chaining or `await` with more readability.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood your question correctly, I believe it should be as simple as:

```
async function combinedResult() {
  return (await getLocal()) || (await getWeb());
}
```

```
const combined = await combinedResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **promise** based version of what you want to do.

```js
const hasData = local => {/* your code to check if local has data */}

const getLocal = () => {/* get from local */}

const getWeb = () => {/* get from web */}

getLocal().then(local => hasData(local) ? local : getWeb())
```